# Calling activity from class that doesnt extend Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, real-time

Is there any way to call an activity from something that doesnt extend Activity? without running it on UI-tread. I want toast-messages in my game, like in candy crush. But I have no idea how to call the toast-activity in an efficient way during real-time.

I know you can use context and get activity from that but it does not run very smoothly. Does anyone have experience with how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Toasts` as well as other components that manipulates the user interface must not be used outside of the UI thread.

What you could do in order to solve your issue, is to design a messaging system between the thread managing you game, and your UI thread. In order to do so, you can use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and its messaging facilities (`sendMessage`, `post`, `postDelayed` ...) to send messages or even `Runnables` to be run on your main thread.

If you create a `Handler` in the main thread, it will automatically associate itself with your main thread's event loop, thus making every work sent to it be executed in the main thread.

A basic example of what you could do would be :

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // The handler is associated with your Activity's thread
    private Handler _handler = new Handler();
    // ...

    private Thread _worker = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          _handler.post(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
          });
        }
    };
};
```

As a shorthand, you could also use [`Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable r)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) that executes the given runnable in the UI thread by default.

Comment: I have a class for my thread, I do not create it in my main activity. But I think I get what you are saying. So if I only have 3-5 messages I can use the shorthand method without it effecting the game to much? Will have to look in to handlers closer, completely new to me

Comment: Yes, your messages will be processed in the UI thread instead. If you're showing a toast at a reasonable pace, performance should not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up! The reason I thought I shouldnt force it onto the UI-thread is because that is what I do with my "level-complete" screen, and that tends to be a bit slow.. But Will try this :)